'Will miss' vs 'Will be missing'
I saw this sentence:

You'll be missing the sunshine once you're back in England.

Would it be wrong if it was written like this?

You'll miss the sunshine once you're back in England.


The verb "miss (something)" indicates a state. And "be missing" is the continuous aspect.  In the present tense it could be used to indicate that the state is current, but temporary:  "I'm missing my brother, but he comes home tomorrow."
It could have the same function in the future (indicating that a future state is expected to be temporary) but it only adds a minor nuance, and isn't normally necessary. Saying "You'll miss the sun" is the normal way to say this.  Since the two aspects have almost the same meaning, there will be some random variation in use. Sometimes people will say "be missing" for no apparent reason.

Of the two versions, your rewrite is in fact the more likely—at least in American English.

Where did you encounter the you’ll be missing version? Sounds to me like Irish English, but I’m no expert there.

It was on an American website ( ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/future-continuous )
